# Sobolev .Absolute.

Tags: sobolev-spaces

We have the result that : $\Omega$ is open set .If $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ then $|u|\in H^1(\Omega)$.My question is :

If $u \in H^2(\Omega) $ .Does $|u| \in H^2(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Consider for example $\Omega = (-1,1)$ and $u(x) =x$.  Then $w(x) = \vert u(x) \vert = \vert x \vert$ satisfies $w'(x) = 1$ for $x>0$ and $w'(x) =-1$ for $x \le 0$.  If $w'$ were in $H^1((-1,1))$, it would be continuous, which it obviously isn't.

Comment: I could be wrong, but if we're looking at Sobolev spaces, do we even need $w'$ to be continuous? My gut says we just need the weak derivative to exist and be square-integrable.

Comment: Sure, in general continuity is not required.  My point here is simply that we have the embedding $H^1((-1,1)) \hookrightarrow C^0((-1,1))$, and so in this particular case it's impossible for $w'$ to belong to $H^1$.  Certainly if $w \in H^2$ then $w' \in H^1$.

Comment: No.  The function $u(x) =x$ is in $H^2$, but $w= \vert u \vert$ is not.

Comment: Yep sorry that's on me, had slightly misinterpreted which spaces we were talking about.